# ecto model parameter not validated?

Tags: validation, elixir, ecto

Might be that I'm missing something, but it feels that this should have been an invalid record:

```
pry(1)> project_params
%{"name" => ""}
pry(2)> changeset
%Ecto.Changeset{action: nil, changes: %{name: ""}, constraints: [], errors: [],
 filters: %{},
 model: %Elix.Project{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built>, id: nil,
  inserted_at: nil, name: nil, updated_at: nil,
  user: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :user is not loaded>,
  user_id: 2}, optional: [], opts: [], params: %{"name" => ""}, prepare: [],
 repo: nil, required: [:name, :user_id],
 types: %{id: :id, inserted_at: Ecto.DateTime, name: :string,
   updated_at: Ecto.DateTime, user_id: :id}, valid?: true, validations: []}
pry(3)> changeset.valid?
true
```

Here's how I have the models defined:

**Project**

```
defmodule Elix.Project do
  use Elix.Web, :model

  schema "projects" do
    field :name, :string
    belongs_to :user, Elix.User

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(name user_id)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  @doc """
  Creates a changeset based on the `model` and `params`.

  If no params are provided, an invalid changeset is returned
  with no validation performed.
  """
  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end
end
```

**User**

```
defmodule Elix.User do
  use Elix.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :crypted_password, :string
    has_many :projects, Elix.Project

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(email password)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  @doc """
  Creates a changeset based on the `model` and `params`.

  If no params are provided, an invalid changeset is returned
  with no validation performed.
  """
  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
    |> unique_constraint(:email)
    |> validate_format(:email, ~r/@/)
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 5)
  end
end
```

and this is the code for the controller create action:

```
def create(conn, %{"project" => project_params}) do
    changeset =
      Ecto.build_assoc(conn.assigns.current_user, :projects) |>
      Project.changeset(project_params)
IEx.pry
    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, project} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Project #{project.name} created succesfully")
        |> redirect(to: project_path(conn, :index))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", project: changeset)
    end
  end
```

I am submitting the form without entering anything on purpose, so that I might test form display errors. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have `plug :scrub_params, "project" when action in [:create, :update]` in your controller?

Comment: That I don't. So an empty string is considered valid?

Comment: Yeah, an empty string is valid. That's the purpose of the `scrub_params`. It turns empty strings to `nil`

Comment: Can you add an answer and I'll mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `changeset.valid?` will only be `false` if the value of `name` is `nil`. Since the value of `name` in your case is an empty string, the changeset will be valid.

The best place to deal with forms passing empty strings as values is in the controller by adding the `scrub_params` plug in like so:

`plug :scrub_params, "project" when action in [:create, :update]`

Check the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#scrub_params/2) for more info on `scrub_params`.

Comment: If the name not being empty is a part of your business logic, I would certainly add a validator for its length like you have for passwords. `scrub_params` is great, but it's easy to accidentally forget to do it in some controller in the future. Putting the length validator in is safer, and you can still put the `scrub_params` in.

Comment: You're right. I was just under the impression that by default ecto would handle it :)